# Why define empty interface for FC in React+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-functional-component

I've seen code like this in a React+Typescript project:

```
interface MyInterface {}

export const MyComponent: FC<MyInterface> = () => {
  // Code here
}
```

What's the point of declaring an empty interface? Why not just use empty curly braces like so?

```
export const MyComponent: FC<{}> = () => {
  // Code here
}
```

React version is 18.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to pass generics to your component unless you need them. In the example, you wrote:

```js
interface MyInterface {}

export const MyComponent: FC<MyInterface> = () => {
   // Code here
}
```

This means you are passing an interface `MyInterface` which will be set as the type of the `props` of the component. For your understanding, the code block above is the same as this (consider MyComponent as a normal function):

```js
interface MyInterface {}

export const MyComponent = (props: MyInterface) => {
  // Code here
}
```

But if you don't have props in your component, then the following code will work fine. You don't need to complicate your code with unnecessary generics.

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
    // Code here
}
```